# Illustrator: wave background with custom defined strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, patterns

Following [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70258/illustrator-how-to-achieve-a-wave-background-letter-without-stokes?answertab=active#tab-top) technique, I am trying to define the stroke ends of the below resulted pattern, but without luck.

What I've done so far:
- I've put a letter over the wavy strokes group (wave pattern created using the `Blending` option) > Selected all artworks, then `Object` > `Clipping Mask` > `Make`.
- Using the `Stroke` Panel, I've tried to modify the endpoint shape of the lines but it looks like it's not a properly way to do it, there is no effect displayed .

Is there any way to achieve the above mentioned effect? Thank you,

[image]

LE: I've managed somehow like this:
- I've created the line pattern using `Blend` option
- `Expand`
- I've Created a new (type) layer
- `Type` > `Create Outlines`
- Select All > `Shape Builder` > Deleted (trimmed) unnecessarily strokes.

The only question that remain, is how to achieve the round strokes ends inside the letter (as we can see, at this phase the Illustrator will make them round outside the letter (outside the outline).

[image]

Comment: Clipping mask does not actually change the paths it just clips the graphics.

Comment: A Joojaa commented, you would need to cut/trim the paths for them to end in certain point with chosen cap

Comment: @joojaa I've tried to apply also [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/illustrator-how-to-reproduce-line-art?answertab=active#tab-top) lesson but not so sure why, I can't reproduce the effect on wave... (may be because I'm an entry-level guy in Illustrator and stuff ...); Anyway, if someone could formulate an elaborate answer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use Offset Path on your crop shape. This creates a new shape which you use to trim the blend.

It's a similar set of steps to those you already have:

1. Create your blend and expand it
2. Type your letter and convert it to outlines (this is your “crop shape”)
3. Use Offset Path on your crop shape (Object menu > Path > Offset Path…)
4. Use a negative value to create a copy of your object that is smaller than your crop shape. You should now have three layers: the blend, your crop shape, and your smaller offset shape.
5. Select your offset shape and your blend (and not your crop shape), and use Shape Builder to remove the protruding lines
6. Hide/delete the offset shape, leaving your original crop shape and the blend.

If you want the rounded path ends to touch your crop shape, when you are using Offset Path, set an offset value that is half your stroke width.

[image: steps]

Comment: Thanks, the effect doesn't apply on every strokes? Looking at the last pic of the process (lower left corner) the strokes are still out of the letter shape ... Am I missing something?

Comment: @user124853 MG_ is not just trimming on that corner